# PDO without mysql_real_escape_string and bindValue

Tags: php, pdo

I'm relatively new to PDO and i have written the following block of code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

foreach($db->query("SELECT id,name FROM names where id = '$id' ") as $row) {
    echo "<p>", ($row['name']), "<br>";
}
```

My uncertainties are:

1. is it safe to OMIT mysql_real_escape_string in the first line since i'm using PDO
2. is it safe to run the query as above without using bind values.

Thanks

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` has no connection to PDO; don't use. it. Re 2. Nope, it's not safe

Comment: @Pekka, why not leave an answer?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary because Pekka has too much reps.... leaving something for newbies like us lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not safe.  PDO doesn't magically escape your queries for you.  Your code, as shown, is wide open to SQL injection.

If you are using variables in your query, don't use `->query`.  Do not try to escape them yourself.  You should be using prepared statements.  That's the way to be safe.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,name FROM names where id = ?');
if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<p>", ($row['name']), "<br>";
    }
}
```

So, yes, you need to use `bindParam`, or `execute`, as shown.

P.S. `mysql_real_escape_string` is *only* for the (deprecated) `mysql_` extension.  It doesn't work with PDO.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, but do you mind clarifying 2 things: 1. Is there a way to make your code a little simpler 2. Can this method also be used where there are no variables involved? Thanks.

Comment: How much simpler do you want it?  What's complicated about it?  If there are no variables to bind, then it's perfectly OK to use `->query()`.

Answer (score 2):

to answer your questions,

1. it is safe to omit `mysql_real_escape_string` as long as you use **bindings** (well.... you can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` with PDO anyway)
2. Nope. It is absolutely unsafe. doesn't matter whether you are using PDO or not.